# Internet says to plant bulbs 3 or 5 times (depending on the bulb) its own depth. What if you're planting in clay soil?

Tags: soil, planting, bulbs, clay

Does the planting depth change when it comes to soil that's more clay then the loamy soil you get at the nurseries? Since clay soil is heavier and has the ability to retain moisture, would it restrict growth or cause moisture damage to not only bulbs but all plants including roses that are generally buried a little over the bud union, again, as per the internet.

Comment: Why the [tag:roses] tag? Roses don't grow from bulbs.

Comment: Ofcourse they dont. I just added them in cause the question relates more to planting in clay soil rather than about bulbs solely.

Comment: Which bulbs, specifically?

Comment: What i find on the internet;
Plant bulbs 1-½ to 5 times their own depth. 

general rule of thumb is to plant the bulb at three times the height of the bulb. So, for example, if your bulb is 2 inches tall, you'd plant it 6 inches deep.

As a rough rule of thumb the depth you plant them wants to be approximately twice to three times the depth of the bulb.
Now it could be any bulb. Lets say daffodils. Question is, do you plant at the same dept even in clay soil?

Comment: @HamidSabir: in general yes: bulbs can also move (small) rocks: they can get through clay, especially when it is humid (and with dry soil (so hard soil) they will not growth). But in any case I would add some sand and organic matter, to improve the soil locally: it will help a lot for nutrients and to store more water.

Comment: I live near a creek and the soil is dense "clay with stones". I find that bulb type plants do very well in my clay soil when they are planted at the recommended depth.